# Getting the selected items count in a kendoMultiSelect footerTemplate

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect, kendo-template

Is it possible to get the selected items count in the [kendoMultiSelect's footerTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/footertemplate)?

I created a [DOJO example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EpIMEYuy) with an attemp to use `instance.dataItems().length` but for some reason, the value is always 0.

```
$("#customers").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  footerTemplate: '#: instance.dataItems().length # item(s) selected'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

due @Aleksandar comment where he points out

> Calling setOptions in an event handler or the respective widget is not
> recommended and can cause an endless loop or a JavaScript error.

I take his suggestion into account and add his solution as an answer.

```
footerTemplate: '<span id="total">#:instance.value().length#</span> item(s) selected',
change:function(e){
  var itmsSelected = e.sender.value().length;
  $("#total").html(itmsSelected);
}
```

**OBSOLETE:**

Guess it's not in an observable object. One of the possible solutions is to change `footerTemplate`

every time a `change` happens on `multiSelect`:

```
var multi = $("#customers").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  change: function() {
    this.setOptions({"footerTemplate": this.value().length +" item(s) selected"});
  },
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  footerTemplate: '0 item(s) selected'
}).getKendoMultiSelect();
```

Example: [Footer template update](https://dojo.telerik.com/AsAfuguX)

Comment: Per the docs, calling the [setOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/widget/methods/setoptions) method can recreate and rebind the widget instance. Calling setOptions in an event handler or the respective widget is not recommended and can cause an endless loop or a JavaScript error. I'd suggest adding a placeholder element and updating it with the count of selected items - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/eqOgofoG).